# Extracting HTML tag content from returned jQuery.get() data

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

The jQuery code:

```
jQuery.get(templateDir + "/file.php",function(data){
        var content = jQuery(data).filter('#content').text();
        console.log(content);
        jQuery("#id").hide().html(content).fadeIn(1000);
},"html");
```

The html structure:

```
<p id="content">content here</p>
<p id="content2">another content here </p
etc....
```

What I'm trying to do is get the inner text/html of the `p#content` element.
I found some solutions online but nothing seems to work.
I tried `find()` and `filter()` as suggested in most, but they didn't solve my problem.

`jQuery(data).text()` works by the way.

What'd be a way to do it then?

Comment: Do you mean you only want the inner text detail of "p" tags that have the class "content" or "p" tags who's inner text is like "content" ?

Comment: Oh sorry! Only the inner text of the p tags that has the id "content". Let me revise my question...

Comment: Is the returned data a list of `p` tags without any wrapper element? If so, filter() should work: http://jsfiddle.net/QqA2T/

Comment: @Tetaxa - Thanks. However, jsfiddle is stuck on "initializing the awesome" hehe. In any case, I did try `.filter()` in my code above, or is my usage of it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try jquery each `$("#testp p[id='content']").each...` ,check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjay225/T3AzF/10/) xtc, it has a wrapper element and one with no wrapper.

EDIT:

Ok so if its coming back as a string, doesn't this example work, cos the html string is being assigned to a variable "testelement" like the variable "content" in your above question?

EDIT:
CODE-EDIT 2:

```
var testelement='<p id="notcontent">Hello</p><p id="content" >content hello</p>';
//old version--> $(testelement).each(function() 
$(testelement).find('p').each(function()   //new version
{

    if($(this).is("p") && this.id=='content')
    {
       alert($(this).text());
       alert($(this).html());
    }

})
```

Comment: Hmmm, is your html coming back as a string or object?

Comment: Man that doesn't not make any sense, try adding two alerts and let me know what comes back, I edited the answer above.

Comment: "false", "testp" (which is the wrapper I added while trying out your solutions).... This probably means it doesn't really go through all of the tags but just the first one. Which is a div by the way

Comment: I don't know if it has something to do with it... and it shouldn't, but I'm using conflict mode (`jQuery(x)` instead of `$(x)`)

Comment: OK cos that code is built for your "<p>" html in your question with no wrapper, if you had a wrapper the line would be "$(testelement).find('p').each(function()" so check the updated answer.

Comment: Hmm better. Seems to alert the third alert with the .text() in it, but the alert is blank... as if there was no content in it...

Comment: We almost there... :) I updated the answer to alert .html() as well as text() and took out the first 2 alerts, try that

Comment: I tried that already but that wasn't the problem at all.
Apparently if I change the <p> tags to <span> tags it works... So for some reason the <p> tags are causing the problem... In any case it doesn't matter to me whether it's a <p> tag or a <span> tag so It's all good now! :) Thank you~

Comment: Thats weird hey, well anyways glad you got it sorted! :)